# Capture a image in specified region in a window

Tags: c#, gdi

So my goal is to make my program that can take a picture in a rectangular region in a specific window.
[image]
Eg.) If I want to capture the black square (full) and only the square (not the any part of the window Y). How would I achieve this ?.

I have tried to use GDI32.dll but I can't seem to be able to configure it to capture only the black square.

```
public static Bitmap CaptureWindow(IntPtr handle) {
 IntPtr hdcSrc = User32.GetWindowDC(handle);

 User32.RECT windowRect = new User32.RECT {
  left = 467,
   right = 1432,
   top = 381,
   bottom = 994
 };

 int width = 965;
 int height = 613;

 IntPtr hdcDest = GDI32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSrc);

 IntPtr hBitmap = GDI32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSrc, width, height);

 IntPtr hOld = GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hBitmap);

 GDI32.BitBlt(hdcDest, windowRect.right, windowRect.bottom, width, height, hdcSrc, windowRect.left, windowRect.top, GDI32.SRCCOPY);

 GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hOld);

 GDI32.DeleteDC(hdcDest);
 User32.ReleaseDC(handle, hdcSrc);

 Image img = Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);

 GDI32.DeleteObject(hBitmap);

 return (Bitmap) img;
}
```

Comment: A screenshot is going to include the overlapping window.  Use [PrintWindow()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-printwindow) instead.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, but how can i capture just the region, I'm going to capture it a lot so i want too decrease the amount of CPU it's going to take

Comment: Work with the author of that program to find a better way.

Comment: It should be `BitBlt(dst, 0, 0, width, height, src, left, top, SRCCOPY)` This method will only work for Win32 programs, like Notepad. In general you have to take screenshot of the whole desktop (use `hdcSrc = GetWindowDC(NULL)`), and make sure your target window is top, then crop the area...